# Changing all projects of a Visual Studio solution to use IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

Does anyone know a trick to change all web projects in a Visual Studio solution so that they use IIS Express.

Imagine converting 100 Web Application projects by clicking each "Properties"...

Comment: When you right click a project, there is a new menu entry called "Use IIS Express". It's not a 5 second solution but it should be a lot faster than opening the properties of each project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way at the moment for converting a lot of projects. A PowerShell script would do the job but I didn't find one and I don't intend to write it the moment.

Comment: The biggest problem is that Visual Studio does not seem to do variable replacement on the `<WebProjectProperties>` section, so you can't do something like setting `<UseIIS>$(MyIISFlag)</UseIIS>`, with `MyIISFlag` defined in some global .xml that you import to all your projects (which is the proper way to do it).

Answer (score 3):

You could edit the .csproj files directly, maybe do a find and replace on all of them. I'm sure there's a more elegant way.

Those settings are stored under:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
    <WebProjectProperties>
              <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
              <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
              <DevelopmentServerPort>56051</DevelopmentServerPort>
              <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
              <IISUrl>
              </IISUrl>
              <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
              <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
              <CustomServerUrl>
              </CustomServerUrl>
              <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
            </WebProjectProperties>
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I know where it's stored. I'm thinking that maybe someone has done something for it. Like a powershell command or something like that. More precisely, in my case, I would prefer to store the information in the csproj.user files (it's a option in "Properties -> Web")

Answer (score 0):

Use a decent editor like notepad++ to do a "replace in files", then just do a global replace of `<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>` with `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` on all `*.csproj` and all `*.csproj.user` files in your directory tree.